# Chrome - Version 29 : Javascript alert Message Comes in top of the window.?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

After Google Chrome 29 th version , javascript alert comes into top of the window.

Upto Version 28 it works fine, which means it properly shows in Middle of the window.

Any Other way to solve this issue or it is a bug ??

Any Idea???

Comment: I think it is just a new layout Chrome uses.

Comment: Ok, can we customize this alert message ?

Comment: Not the native one, no. You can use some JS to create your own though

Comment: @Bojangles could you please give me any suggestion or sample code ?

Comment: No. There's plenty of stuff on Google which you can [find yourself](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+alert&oq=jquery+alert). Please put _some_ effort into this - it's _your_ problem, not mine